# Inserting data into azure table storage?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I have a enity say

```
 class NewEntity : TableEntity 
 {
         Set partition key and Row key in constructor.

          public NewEnum a { get; set; }
  }   

     enum NewEnum
   {
       Sat,
       Sun        
   }
```

Now when i insert this enity into table storage using
       **TableOperation.Insert((ITableEntity) entity)** it doesnt insert NewEnum into the table, please help me here.

Answer (score 0):

`Enum` type is not supported. Here is the list of supported types: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/Understanding-the-Table-Service-Data-Model